# Compare multiple numeric columns to determine record similarity

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have data with an ID and many columns of integer numeric values from -5 to 5 including 0.

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ COL1 ║ COL2 ║ COL3 ║ COL4 ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ A  ║   -5 ║   -2 ║    0 ║   -2 ║
║ B  ║    0 ║    1 ║   -1 ║    3 ║
║ C  ║    1 ║   -2 ║   -3 ║    1 ║
║ D  ║   -1 ║   -1 ║    5 ║    0 ║
║ E  ║    2 ║   -3 ║    1 ║   -2 ║
║ F  ║   -3 ║    1 ║   -2 ║   -1 ║
║ G  ║   -4 ║   -1 ║   -1 ║   -3 ║
╚════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

I want to group the ID's by similarity across all columns.
For instance ID A and G above a similar because their values in each column are quite similar.

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ COL1 ║ COL2 ║ COL3 ║ COL4 ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ A  ║   -5 ║   -2 ║    0 ║   -2 ║
║ G  ║   -4 ║   -1 ║   -1 ║   -3 ║
╚════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

On the other hand A and B are dissimilar

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ COL1 ║ COL2 ║ COL3 ║ COL4 ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ A  ║   -5 ║   -2 ║    0 ║   -2 ║
║ B  ║    0 ║    1 ║   -1 ║    3 ║
╚════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

For a given ID pair I am thinking about calculating the difference in each column and then adding the differences to get a similarity score (larger number less similar). At this time its the best idea I have, but I am open to more accurate or effective methods.

Comment: Be careful, to use the absolute value of the distance, else some differences might cancel each other out, e.g.: `(5 - 0) + (0 - 5)`. According to your definition, those two would be rather different, but a naive implementation will tag them identical.

Comment: Why not sum values of absolute differences: `score = ABS(5 - 0) + ABS(0 - 5) + ...`

Comment: The trouble here is what determines "Similar" if each one is off by 1 is that similar? how about 2?  how about if 3 of the 4 are the same and one of them is off by 2... So is the comparison over the whole ROW and all 4 columns... There's too much fuzzy logic here for defining "Similar"

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this (using the absolute difference between the values in the columns) would be as follows:

```
with all_compared as (
  select a.id as ID,
         b.id as CompID,
         abs(a.col1 - b.col1) + abs(a.col2 - b.col2) + abs(a.col3 - b.col3) + abs(a.col4 - b.col4) as TotalDiff
    from stuff a,
         stuff b
   where a.id != b.id
  ),
  ranked_data as (
  select ID, 
         CompID,
         TotalDiff,
         rank() over (partition by ID order by TotalDiff) Rnk 
    from all_compared
  )
select *
  from ranked_data
 where rnk = 1;
```

I have done a SQL Fiddle showing how I got to this step by step here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fef06/14

You would then need to decide how to handle ties as this gives the output:

[image]

This uses a Cartesian product (all rows in one table joined to all in another) with a self join to compare each row with each other row and sums the absolute difference between the col1's ,2's etc. We then reduce this by ranking the total difference and selecting the top rank.

Another approach to this would be to use the squared distance rather than absolute difference, this would amplify the larger differences so you would need to consider whether you want this or not.

**Example** 1,1 &  0,5 would get 25 as (0-5)^2 is 25, which would count as less similar than 0,3 & -4,-1 which would get 18 (3^2 + 3^2) where as with the absolute differences the first would be counted as more similar as all differences are treated with equal weight.

The squared distance version is:

```
with all_compared as (
  select a.id as ID,
         b.id as CompID,
         power(a.col1 - b.col1, 2) + 
           power(a.col2 - b.col2, 2) + 
           power(a.col3 - b.col3, 2) + 
           power(a.col4 - b.col4, 2) as SqDist
    from stuff a,
         stuff b
   where a.id != b.id
  ),
  ranked_data as (
  select ID, 
         CompID,
         SqDist,
         rank() over (partition by ID order by SqDist) Rnk 
    from all_compared
  )
select *
  from ranked_data
 where rnk = 1;
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use both and just use the squared distance to resolve ties:

```
with all_compared as (
  select a.id as ID,
         b.id as CompID,
         abs(a.col1 - b.col1) + abs(a.col2 - b.col2) + abs(a.col3 - b.col3) + abs(a.col4 - b.col4) as TotalDiff,
         power(a.col1 - b.col1, 2) + 
           power(a.col2 - b.col2, 2) + 
           power(a.col3 - b.col3, 2) + 
           power(a.col4 - b.col4, 2) as SqDist
    from stuff a,
         stuff b
   where a.id != b.id
  ),
  ranked_data as (
  select ID, 
         CompID,
         TotalDiff,
         SqDist,
         rank() over (partition by ID order by TotalDiff, SqDist) Rnk 
    from all_compared
  )
select *
  from ranked_data
 where rnk = 1;
```

[image]